# Segfault on Windows but not Linux (GDB info included) - C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segfault in Windows but not in Linux (same program). Using GDB (minGW), I get the following information:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 21 0x7c8024f0 in 
ReleaseMutex () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll

The program runs to completion on a Linux system. The crash is during a recursive call in this function:

```
    void recursive_paint_char(int x,int y,int **inimage,int new_color,int fore_color)
{

/* 
   This routine paints the connected object around the pixel x,y in image inimage
   to the color new_color. The foreground color is assumed to be fore_color.
*/
 int        i;
 int        xt,yt;

 inimage[x][y]=new_color;
 for (i=0;i<8;i++)
 {

  xt=x+xc[i];
  yt=y+yc[i];
  if (inimage[xt][yt]==fore_color) 
  {
    printf("this statement prints\n"); 
   recursive_paint_char(xt,yt,inimage,new_color,fore_color);
   printf("this statement never prints\n"); 
  }
 }
}
```

The recursion goes to about 171,000 calls before segfaulting

Comment: I cannot guarantee there is not a memory leak on linux, but the program does handle large data sets (50 sets of ~100-200 images) to completion

Comment: Assuming that you've got about 48 bytes on the stack for each call, 171000 calls would take about 8MB of stack. So your linux machine evidently is set up for a larger stack than your windows machine.

Comment: Does it not matter that the recursion is tail-recursive?

Comment: A tail call has to be the very last thing the function does. In your case, the recursive call is within a loop, so it can't be implemented as a tail call.

Answer (score 0):

user3386109 answered the Question - the problem appears to be stack size.